# Windows Phone 8.1 development. C#. JSON

Tags: c#, json, post, windows-phone-8.1, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently developing a windows phone 8.1 application which needs a login from some server using a WEB API. It takes multiple parameters as POST data and i need to recieve a JSON object to handle multiple the numerous return parameters. Kindly help me.

The following code sends a request to the web server and i get a HttpResponseMessage. My question is how do i extract data from this response.

```
            Uri theUri = new Uri("myURI");
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient aClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = theUri.Host;
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TodoItem2)); //TodoItem2 is my class type of post data
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        jsonSer.WriteObject(ms, x);
        ms.Position = 0;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);

        StringContent theContent = new StringContent(sr.ReadToEnd(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);


            if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                tblMsg.Text = "Login Successful..";
            }

            else
            {
                tblMsg.Text = "Incorrect Credentials";
            } 
        }
```

Comment: You need to try something on your own. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Kindly provide your existing code and narrow down your question to a specific problem.

Comment: @Fred now check the code.

Comment: Is this a Silverlight project or WinRT?

Comment: Silverlight Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this:

```
    string jsonMessage;
    using (Stream responseStream = await aResponse .Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Now if you have your received content you got json in jsonMessage variable.

If you would like to convert it to object, you must create a class, for example class named User. You can convert json to C# object using Json.NET library:

```
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonMessage);
```

Json.NET site: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.